# In python, how can I use regex to replace square bracket with parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I have a list :`list = [1,2,3]`. And I would like to convert that into a string with parentheses: `string = (1,2,3)`.

Currently I am using string replace `string = str(list).replace('[','(').replace(']',')')`. But I think there is a better way using regex.sub. But I have no idea how to do it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nope - what you are doing looks good to me.

Comment: str.replace(old, new[, max])

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you do indeed have a list, then:

```
>>> s  = [1,2,3]
>>> str(tuple(s))
'(1, 2, 3)'
```

Comment: Should have read closer.  I just assumed that OP had a string that was formatted like a list.  +1.  This is the way I would do it in my real code I think.

Comment: But I have another one with string, then it doesn't work so well.
>>> s = ['1']
>>> str(tuple(s))
"('1',)"

Comment: `str(tuple(s)).rstrip(',)') + ')'`
'(1)'

Comment: Doesn't work for list with single element. It will add a trailing comma like "(1,)"

Answer (score 7):

You could use `string.maketrans` instead -- I'm betting it runs faster than a sequence of `str.replace` and it scales better to more single character replacements.

```
>>> import string
>>> table = string.maketrans('[]','()')
>>> s = "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
>>> s.translate(table)
'(1, 2, 3, 4)'
```

You can even use this to remove characters from the original string by passing an optional second argument to `str.translate`:

```
>>> s = str(['1','2'])
>>> s
"['1', '2']"
>>> s.translate(table,"'")
'(1, 2)'
```

In python3.x, the string module is gone and you gain access to `maketrans` via the `str` builtin:

```
table = str.maketrans('[]','()')
```

Comment: It doesn't work so well on list of string. >>>s = ['1']
>>> str(s).translate(table)
"('1')"

Comment: @Winston -- It actually handles that quite easily.  See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

There are a billion ways to do this, as demonstrated by all the answers. Here's another one:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
my_str = "(%s)" % str(my_list).strip('[]')
```

or make it recyclable:

```
list_in_parens = lambda l: "(%s)" % str(l).strip('[]')
my_str = list_in_parens(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

`str([1,2,3]).replace('[','(').replace(']',')')`

Should work for you well, and it is forward and backward compatible as far as I know.

as far as re-usability, you can use the following function for multiple different types of strings to change what they start and end with:

```
def change(str_obj,start,end):
    if isinstance(str_obj,str) and isinstance(start,str) and isinstance(end,str):
        pass
    else:
        raise Exception("Error, expecting a 'str' objects, got %s." % ",".join(str(type(x)) for x in [str_obj,start,end]))
    if len(str_obj)>=2:
        temp=list(str_obj)
        temp[0]=start
        temp[len(str_obj)-1]=end
        return "".join(temp)
    else:
         raise Exception("Error, string size must be greater than or equal to 2. Got a length of: %s" % len(str_obj))
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly. But I want a better implementation. Maybe regex is a good way.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use regex I guess this would work. But the other posted solutions are probably more efficient and/or easy to use.

```
import re

string = str(list)
re.sub(r"[\[]", "(", string)
re.sub(r"[\]]", ")", string)
```

@mgilson something like this you mean?

```
def replace_stuff(string):
    string_list = list(string)
    pattern = re.compile(r"[\[\]]")
    result = re.match(pattern, string)
    for i in range(len(result.groups())):
        bracket = result.group(i)
        index = bracket.start()
        print(index)
        if bracket == "[":
            string_list[index] = "("
        else:
            string_list[index] = ")"

    return str(string_list)
```

It doesn't quite work, for some reason len(result.groups()) is always 0 even though the regex should find matches. So couldn't test whether this is faster but because I couldn't get it to work I couldn't test it. I have to leave for bed now so if someone can fix this go ahead.

Comment: Great. Is it possible to do it on 1 line?

Comment: I'm no regex expert at all but I don't think so. Because you want to replace with two different strings "(" and ")" and you can only replace one regex with one string using re.sub.

Comment: @DaanLubbers -- You *could* define a function to pass to `re.sub` which would then take the match object and decide whether to substitute a `'('` or a `')'`.  It might even be slightly more efficient (you'd need to `timeit` to find out), but it would be slightly more code as you'd need to define the function properly, etc, etc..

Comment: Updated the post with a function which should do what you asked (I think). I have no clue if it could be fast as I don't know how long the re functions take but it at least takes way more effort to code. I am quite intrigued now whether this is faster or not. Sadly as you can read I don't know why it doesn't work as is and have to go, maybe you can have a swing at it?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
"(" + strng.strip('[]') + ")"
```

It works for both single element and multi-element lists.

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> strng = str(lst)
>>> "(" + strng.strip('[]') + ")"
'(1, 2, 3)'


>>> lst = [1]
>>> strng = str(lst)
>>> "(" + strng.strip('[]') + ")"
'(1)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'({0})'.format(', '.join(str(x) for x in list))
```

By the way, it's not a good idea to name your own variables `list` since it clashes with the built-in function. Also `string` can conflict with the module of the same name.

Comment: @Winston I guess your python version is older than 2.7/3.1. The edit fixes it for you.